# Cross Data Center Redis Cluster

Tags: redis, redis-cluster

We are trying to setup a redis cluster in a multi-datacenter environment, with one cluster setup in one datacenter and the other cluster in the other datacenter, in this case, is there a way to setup cross datacenter replication of cluster using redis cluster ? Has anyone setup redis cluster in this way or are there better ways to do this ?

Comment: I would suggest looking at [twemproxy](https://github.com/twitter/twemproxy) rather than trying to do this using the native replication/clustering features in Redis.

The latencies and the chances of inter-site link failures are likely to impact your cache performance.

Comment: @JimDennis we did look at twmproxy and dynomite , but I was hoping we could use native redis clustering for this if possible

Comment: @PremilJacob did you find a solution? can you share what you decided?

Answer (score 0):

As far as i have seen, only [Dynomite](https://github.com/Netflix/dynomite/wiki/Topology) seems to solve this problem.

Else we need to implement our own by having a setup like this:

DataCenter1:

```
[multiple redis clients]===>[localProxy-DC1]====> TWEMPROXY-DC1 ===> [Multiple Redis Single Instances with Sentinel]
```

DataCenter-2:

```
[localProxy-DC1] ====replicates commands async===> TWEMPROXY-DC2 ====> [Multiple Redis Single Instances with Sentinel]
```